# google maps turn-by-turn navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, routes

I writing a web app(html5 and angular) where I use google maps to create a route. If the user uses the web app via mobile phone I would like to open a native google map app to show the route turn-by-turn navigation. Is this possible?

Thank you

Edit: I can invoke a native with the following link right? 
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=New+York&daddr=San+Francisco

Is it possible for me add waypoints in between?

Comment: You can use it (**https://github.com/dflourusso/ng-gmaps-waypoints**) to add way points. If you is using Cordova, you can use it (**https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/External-Service**) to open native google maps